# Plotly Map plotting lat-lng points only showing for one day, rather than for all days

Tags: plotly, mapbox, timeserieschart

I am creating an animated Plotly scatter map where each point represents a "tiny home" listing. The point populates on the date the listing is created:
[image: Initial View]

But as you can see (see below), the points don't persist. That is, the point representing that listing only populates on the day it's created.
[image: Updated View]

I would like for a point to persist throughout the entire visualization once populated. The visualizations I've found seem to do this without additional tweaking, and I can't figure out why this is happening this my plot. Data is formatted as seen below:

```
                                                            id     area     city          state lat         lng         price       text
createdat   title                               
2021-02-08  Fully-Converted Diesel School Bus Home          23421   314     Brandon         SD  43.600000   -96.590000  37000.0     Brandon,SD
            NEW Luxurious - Full Kitchen - Full Bath 26'    23419   221     Oregon City     OR  45.330000   -122.570000 99000.0     Oregon City,OR
2021-02-07  Beautiful New Container Home For Sale           23418   320     Liberty City    TX  32.380000   -94.870000  65000.0     Liberty City,TX
            3 Bed 2 Bath Tiny Duplex                        23417   399     Kennesaw        GA  34.000000   -84.620000  27800.0     Kennesaw,GA
            Beautiful Off Grid Skoolie (Ready To Roam)      23416   143     The Hills       TX  30.310000   -97.940000  52500.0     The Hills,TX
```

Any insight or guidance on how to ensure these points are created on their creation data and persist throughout the entire visualization would be so helpful! Thank you!!!